# Expectation of $n$-dimensional Inverse Bessel Process

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I think the main problem for me is to calculate the integral of $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{2t}}}{\sqrt{x^2+r^2}}r^{n-1}dr,n\geq2$$
For n=2, change of variable $y=\sqrt{x^2+r^2}$ would work well. But I'm stuck when n>2.
The background of this problem is to calculate the expectation of n+1-dimension Inverse Bessel Process starts at $(1,0,...0)$, where the orginal integral is $$(2\pi t)^{-(n+1)/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\frac{e^{-||\overrightarrow{x}-(1,0,...0)||^2/(2t)}}{||\overrightarrow{x}||}dx$$
I try to first integrate the last $n$ coordinates and change them into spherical coordinates, taking out the constant, if I'm correct, you will get the integral at the beginning.

You are free to use functions like erf() or cdf of Normal distribution or Gamma function to express your result, if no such expression exists, a recursive formula is also desired.

Comment: I put it into Mathematica.  When $n$ is even it seems to give answers in terms of the erf function.  When $n$ is odd, it invokes hypergeometric functions.  I take that as a sign the problem is very hard.

Comment: Thank you for working it out in Mathematica, I tryied the online version but time always exceeds, could you please paste the result here as a hint so that some one might figure it out how to do it?